# Elixir - Nerves BLE Library Recommendation

Tags: elixir, bluetooth-lowenergy, nerves-project

I'm working on an IoT project and I recently discovered [nerves](https://www.nerves-project.org/). At the moment I'm using node.js with noble, that I would like to replace with nerves, for the gateway on Raspberry Pi. I didn't find anything similar and maintained for Elixir.

Does anyone know a library for BLE in Elixir?

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately BLE is not well supported on Nerves. You can see the current options on [this issue](https://github.com/nerves-project/nerves/issues/210) on the Nerves project repository.

Final comment from the Nerves maintainer:

> Closing. If you're interested in Bluetooth on Nerves, please check out
>   https://github.com/verypossible/harald. File issues there or go to the
>   Elixir lang slack's #nervesbluetooth channel support.

Comment: I feared this answer :(. I'm wondering why there is so poor commitment for BLE in opensource (except for iOS and android)...